How to join all rows of one table to a column of another table that is not in the first table?
First table is only one column, just customer ID:
ID
___
1122
2222
3333

Second table is the product information:
    | State| User   | Limit
    | CA   | JM21   | 100
    | OH   | JD11   | 200 
    | WV   | KM34   | 250

I need to join all product information to each customer ID. My question is if there is a way to cross join all the data from the second table to each individual row in the first table?
I want the final table to look like:
|ID |State | User   | Limit
1122| CA   | JM21   | 100
1122| OH   | JD11   | 200 
1122| WV   | KM34   | 250
2222| CA   | JM21   | 100
2222| OH   | JD11   | 200 
2222| WV   | KM34   | 250

Thanks!

in sql you would write a SELECT DISTINCT ID   | State| User FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2

why are there multiple rows in the second table, if they are all the same?

Your terminology and data do not align (product information but no product information) I think your example data needs clarification.

Yes, use the CROSS JOIN join.
data one ; input id@@; datalines ;
1122 2222 3333
;
data two; input State $ User $ Limit ; datalines ;
CA JM21 100
OH JD11 200 
WV KM34 250
;
proc sql ;
  create table want as 
  select one.*, two.*
  from one cross join two 
  ;


Learn more from the documentation
joined-table Component

This worked, thank you!

cross join is the correct method as suggested.
proc sql;
create table want as
select t1.*, t2.*
from have1 as t1, have2 as t2;
quit;

If you want a data step approach (not recommended) here is a SAS reference for it.

wouldn't that result in an n*m sized table?

@njzk2 yes, but I suspect the OP needs to clarify the requirements.

That does not work, the ID value from the first table is blank
